# Apache and rewrite/redirect in htaccess to different folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know it's not original question but I've read several posts and questions here and still can't figure it out.

I'm on localhost (apache server) and default server home is in /var/www. There is a folder 'project' with several subfolders, one of them is called web with index.php file. So now if I want to go to index, I need to use full url localhost/project/web/.

I want to make it better so that if you go to localhost/project you are either redirected to localhost/project/web/ or the url remains same but it works (sorry for this naive formulation).

In .htaccess I changed directory index but then all links (since they are relative) were not working.

I tried this .htaccess in /var/www/project:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/$ ./web/
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
Options -Indexes
```

But it's not working, going to localhost/project tries to list the project directory (it is not allowed due to Options -Indexes, which is what I wanted). I need it to be independent of the 'localhost' in url because it have to work anywhere (if .htaccess is allowed)

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedirectMatch doesn't have a base like mod_rewrite does. Even if it's in the htaccess file in the /project directory, you need the full URI:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/project/$ /project/web/
```

If you wanted it to go to /project/web/index.php **without** a browser redirect (meaning the address in the URL bar on the browser stays at localhost/project/) you need to internally rewrite the URI using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ web/index.php [L]
```

Note that mod_rewrite uses the base URI that the htaccess file is in (but the "prefix" or leading slash is removed).

Comment: Thank you! The first one is working just fine. The rewriteengine throws some "internal server error" but it doesn't matter, the first one is ok